# How to stop an image which moves by animation?

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to move an image from left to right on layout, but not by dragging. I want it to go automatically when something happened. So, i found an animation like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" >

<translate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="200"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:fillAfter="true" />

</set>
```

But the problem is i couldn't find how to make it stop there! It's just went back directly. Any suggestion please?

Here is my Java code:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
        runOnRight(this, image);
    }

static Animation runOnRight(Activity ctx, View target) {
      Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx,
                                                         R.anim.slide_left_to_right);
      target.startAnimation(animation);
      return animation;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the [View.onAnimationEnd()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onAnimationEnd%28%29) callback is fired, you can set the new View postion with [View.layout(int, int, int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#layout%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29). The View.layout call assign size and position to your view. Refer to the documentation for more information

Answer (score 1):

set `FillAfter` to `true` in your animation set xml

Comment: i added this android:fillAfter="true" as your suggestion, but it still doesn't stop there.

Answer (score 0):

use the field FillAfter="true" which will stops at the end.
  just like following.